# Как написать круговой эффект в карусели?

Tags: jquery

Как написать карусель, чтобы листало по кругу, т.е. не было конца карусели? Плагины не предлагать. Вот что у меня есть [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Hancock_888/HbNtQ/) здесь смысл если больеш 6 элементов то появляются стрелки, при ховере срабатывает эффект анимации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все элементы лежат в контейнере, который смещается, верно?

Я делал вот как: в критический момент — когда при следующем «перелистывании» элементы могут закончиться — добавлял после (или перед — смотря в какую сторону листаешь) текущего видимого контейнера его копию. А для смещения я уменьшал (или увеличивал) `margin` первого контейнера, при этом всегда сохраняя `margin` других копий = 0 (чтоб не наезжали один на другой).

Answer (score 1):

Выбирайте на свой вкус: [карусели, ротаторы и скроллеры для жквери](http://followdesign.com/development/2011/11/19/jquery-karuseli-rotatory-i-skrollery-chast-1.html)